# HTML5 form with cgi app

Tags: php, html, forms

I am doing a html5 form, it asks for build a form with teacher's cgi.
I am confuse how to submit form information to his cgi.
It return an error values.

It should return a list of track title, if we submit it right.
Here is part of my code.

```
<FORM ACTION="xx.cgi">
<INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="Field" SIZE="25"><BR>
<INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" NAME="Submit" VALUE="Submit">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure where you get all the values, but this should get you pointed in the right direction.

Your form must have:

```
enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
```

To be compatible with your cgi script.

```
$time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");    
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$page = parse_url($_ENV["SCRIPT_NAME"],PHP_URL_PATH);
echo <<<EOT
<form action="xx.cgi" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"><div>
<input type="text" name="album" size="25"><br/>
Subs: <input type="radio" name="subs" value="1"> Yes
<input type="radio" name="subs" value="2"> No
<br/><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
<input type="hidden" name="tracktime" value="$time" />
<input type="hidden" name="ip" value="$ip" />
<input type="hidden" name="page" value="$page" />
</div></form>
EOT;
```

Comment: Thanks, i got the idea from you. It works very well. I set up value and change mothod to the post.

Comment: The key was `enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`

Comment: Actually, our teacher setup all th stuff, it just unclear on the paper, when i setup method to "post" and preset value, it works. I do not think he setup enctype. Because we got the value on the paper. Btw thanks for helping >.<

Comment: When I submitted the form without the`enctype` I got an error from the cgi.  It could be Browser dependent.